# Adding preload to css files in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am new to WordPress and am trying to preload certain css files. I understand that they are loaded into the head using `wp_enqueue_style()`, so I am trying to access the html generated from that to add `rel="preload"`.

So far it looks like this

```
wp_enqueue_script('main-style', 'styles/main-style.css', false, null);

add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'preload_filter', 10, 2);

function preload_filter($html, $handle) {
   if (strcmp($handle, 'main-style') == 0) {
      $html = str_replace("rel='stylesheet'", "rel='preload' as='style' ", $html);
   }

   return $html;
}
```

Although when I add this `preload_filter` function my css fails to load completely, and not just for the specified stylesheet... Am I missing anything in trying to do this, or is there a simpler method? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you adding `main-style.css` in `wp_enqueue_script()` it must be `wp_enqueue_style()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To enqueue style file, you need to use `wp_enqueue_style` function. You used `wp_enqueue_script` which is used to enqueue JavaScript file.

```
wp_enqueue_style('preload-style', 'styles/main-style.css', false, null);
```

And you need to use `style_loader_tag` filter to filter the HTML link tag of an enqueued style.

```
add_filter( 'style_loader_tag',  'preload_filter', 10, 2 );
function preload_filter( $html, $handle ){
    if (strcmp($handle, 'preload-style') == 0) {
        $html = str_replace("rel='stylesheet'", "rel='preload' as='style' ", $html);
    }
    return $html;
}
```

But you used `script_loader_tag` filter which is used to filter `<script>` tag.

Comment: Hmm strange, it seems even when I make these changes the css files that I have enqueued aren't loading at all with the preload_function there

Comment: You need to load the CSS file later again. Please check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content
In other words, you should have 2 lines (preload and load) in your HTML. `<link rel="preload" href="style.css" as="style">` and `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">` together. If you can't solve the problem, feel free to DM me.

Comment: Ahh okay so I haven't loaded again. So I should wp_enqueue_style again because I have preloaded?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. If you face any other issue feel free to contact me via skype (live:rsm0128)

Comment: So I've got the preload part working now, but I need to load the CSS file again now, should I do it using wp_enqueue_style again (as it was done the first time before adding preload filter)

Comment: Instead of enqueue style again, you can use onload method.
`$html = str_replace("rel='stylesheet'", "rel='preload' as='style' onload='this.rel=\"stylesheet\"'", $html);`

Answer (score 0):

(Can't reply, but extends this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66640766/1898675)

This modification use the noscript fallback, which is recommended by google for defer css. https://web.dev/defer-non-critical-css/#optimize

```
add_filter( 'style_loader_tag',  'preload_filter', 10, 2 );
    function preload_filter( $html, $handle ){
    if (strcmp($handle, 'preload-style') == 0) {
        $fallback = '<noscript>' . $html . '</noscript>';
        $preload = str_replace("rel='stylesheet'", "rel='preload' as='style' onload='this.rel=\"stylesheet\"'", $html);
        $html = $preload . $fallback;
    }
    return $html;
}
```